# jQuery UI Autocomplete not working locally

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I'm trying to use autocomplete with JQuery UI, but am having some trouble. My main issue right now is I want to store whatever is being autocompleted into a variable for me to manipulate, but I can't seem to get access to that data. Instead, I get the following error in my console: "Uncaught ReferenceError: autocomplete is not defined". If you go to my JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/uMqyn/769/) and look at lines 10-14 in the JavaScript area, you will see where I am trying to do this.

Here is my HTML:

```
<!-- language: HTML -->

Search: <input class="search-variety-autocomplete" />

<div class="Arugula-DragonsTongue option" style="display:none;">
  Arugula - Dragon's Tongue
</div>
<div class="Arugula-Astro option" style="display:none;">
  Arugula - Astro
</div>
<div class="t11 Kale-Starbor option" style="display:none;">
  Kale - Starbor
</div>
<div class="Basil-Genovese option" style="display:none;">
  Basil - Genovese
</div>
```

Here is my JavaScript:

```
$("input.search-variety-autocomplete").keypress(function () {
    $('.option').fadeOut("fast");
});
$('input.search-variety-autocomplete').autocomplete({
        open: function( event, ui ) {
        $(".ui-autocomplete").hide();
    },
    minLength: 3,
    source: ["Arugula - Astro", "Arugula - Dragon's Tongue", "Kale - Starbor", "Basil - Genovese"],
    response: function(event, ui){
      //var itemValue = ui-autocomplete.value;
      //var itemValue = ui-autocomplete;
      var itemValue = ui-autocomplete-input;  // If I type "bas", this should equal "Basil - Genovese" 
      console.log(itemValue);
      //var $itemClass = itemValue.replace(/ /g, '').replace("'", "");
      //$('.' + $itemClass).fadeIn("fast");
    }
});
```

Comment: You seems to be destroying the autocomplete and reinitializing it with the second call to autocomplete... and the fiddle throws different errors with different versions of jQuery UI.. are you sure you're following the documentation..?

Comment: You can use the latest versions of jquery and jquery UI in jsfiddle, they are at the top of the list of versions. The bottom are the **oldest** you can use.

Comment: I edited my code to only call autocomplete once and showed an error message I'm getting. I also updated the link to my JSFiddle. It is quite possible that I'm not following the documentation well enough as it is my first time using JQuery UI. I Googled my error message, but with no luck. I'll try to take a closer look today.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/uMqyn/765/ Also to access the widget data you need to use `ui-autocomplete` to access it. jQuery takes the full widget name space and replaces the `.` with hyphens and uses that as the data key for a widget.

Comment: I may not have fully understood you. I'm trying to access the data and save it in a variable, but i keep getting "Uncaught ReferenceError: autocomplete is not defined". Here is my new JSFiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/uMqyn/768/

Comment: I have updated my entire question above and it will likely be more simple to follow and help me with now. My main issue is accessing data. I will continue trying to figure it out myself as well.

Comment: How are you including the relevant jQuery files in your page? Please post that code as well.

Comment: @j08691 I am currently using JQuery 2.1.4 and JQuery UI 1.11.4 in my JSFiddle. If you're asking how to change that, just click on where it says "JAVASCRIPT" with the gear right next to it in the top right of the JavaScript area. To be clear, the error I'm currently getting is in my JSFiddle. I haven't tried using the updated code in my application yet.

Comment: No, I'm asking about the code in the page you're having trouble with locally.

Comment: Here is the section of where my scripts are linked. I will update my version of jQuery UI if I get it working in JSFiddle http://i.stack.imgur.com/cel4s.jpg